# Detect if a string contains a phone number in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if a given string contains a phone number in Dart, whether starting with a country code or zero. I have searched for various methods to see if a string contains a phone number but haven't found any. The only search I'm getting is on how to validate a phone number in Dart.

The following is the code I'm currently using with no luck. I have tried a bunch of other stuffs but the following is the latest.

```
void detectPhoneNumber(String message){
  if(message.contains(RegExp(r'^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10}$'))){
    print("A phone number was found!");
    return; 
  } 
  print("no luck!");
}

void main(){
  detectPhoneNumber("RG44NO7QR2 Confirmed. xxx sent to  Grace 0712345678 on 4/7/23 at 10:52 AM.  ");
}
```

Comment: A few things. `^` says match at the beginning of the string; `$` says match at the end of the string. We don't want those. Also, `{10}` requires 10 more digits after the first `09`... which seems like too many for the phone number, or the phone number is too short. I got it to match with `r'(?:[+0]7)?[0-9]{8}'` (also changed the prefix from 9 to 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the String inside your Phone number via Regular Expression.

```
bool containsPhoneNumber(String input) {
  // Regular expression pattern for a basic phone number
  final pattern = r'\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b';

  // Create a regular expression object
  final regex = RegExp(pattern);

  // Check if the input matches the pattern
  return regex.hasMatch(input);
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Would you be free to explain what is happening inside the regex? Like If I needed to add more numbers to accommodate even country code? Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you're using in your `detectPhoneNumber` function is not correctly formatted to match a phone number.
Also, you're using the `contains` method, which checks if a string contains a substring, but it doesn't support regular expressions.

```dart
void detectPhoneNumber(String message) {
  RegExp phoneRegex = RegExp(r'^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10}$');

  if (phoneRegex.hasMatch(message)) {
    print("A phone number was found!");
    return;
  }

  print("No luck!");
}

void main() {
  detectPhoneNumber("RG44NO7QR2 Confirmed. xxx sent to Grace 0712345678 on 4/7/23 at 10:52 AM.");
}
```